# 上帝也哭泣, Cantonese version, is this bit of lyrics correct?

Tags: meaning, pronunciation

[The song in the title](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1fwV12InJ0&list=RDY1fwV12InJ0) is by Wang Jie. The lyrics can be found [here](http://michelegorini.blogspot.it/2017/08/all-chinese-songs-i-have-met.html). However, ever since I first met this song, I was puzzled by this bit:

> 谁飘涌这里未能别去？

This should transliterate to:

> Seoi4 piu1 cung1/zung2 ze5-leoi5 mei6 nang4 bit6 heoi3?

What I hear in the video linked above, 00:50-00:54, is:

> Seoi piu-hyup ze-leoi mei nam pið heoi?

Now the `nam` could be explained away by assimilation, the `pið` has the weird /ð/ instead of /t/ at sytllable end which may be just a quirk of the singer's pronunciation, and the `p` which is probably just the root voiceless value of Jyutping `b` surfacing as sometimes happens - and similar things happen in Wang Jie's mandarin singing too. But the `hyup` is puzzling. Is there any explanation besides "Wang Jie made a weird mistake in his native tongue and this should actually be `cung` or `zung`"? Perhaps another word with similar meaning in Cantonese starting with the same `piu` and ending in `hyup` or something close to it?

Comment: The words should be 漂来. Wang Jie is a native of Taiwan, where traditional mandarine is spoken, so Cantonese to him is a foreign language. That said, his pronunciation is something which can arouse different views but which is also his trade mark with a very high distinction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just relistened to the song (in perhaps another video) and realized I was mishearing (probably because of instruments): he actually pronounces `jung`, which makes it a `piu1-jung2` according to [here](http://ykyi.net/dict/index.php?char=%E6%B6%8C).

Answer (score 1):

He pounced it correctly and match with lyrics.

Multiple pronunciation of 涌. "yung2"
[http://ykyi.net/dict/index.php?char=涌](http://ykyi.net/dict/index.php?char=%E6%B6%8C)

E.g. 暗涌